# Vue 3 Loop function working but I have problem when I play a different track from the array

Tags: arrays, loops, vuejs3, watch, audio-player

I have this function and watcher in the script setup with the isRepeatOn variable initially set to false.

```
        const loopCurrentTrack = () => {
        isRepeatOn.value = !isRepeatOn.value;
        if (isRepeatOn.value) {
            audio.value.addEventListener("ended", function () {
            audio.value.currentTime = 0;
            audio.value.play();
            });
        } else {
            audio.value.removeEventListener("ended", null);
        }
        }


        watch(
        () => isTrackTimeCurrent.value,
        (time) => {
            if (time === isTrackTimeTotal.value && !isRepeatOn.value) {
            useSong.nextSong(currentTrack.value);
            }
        }
        );
```

Here is the repeat button:

```
  <div class="p-2 ml-2 hover:bg-[#5a5a5a] text-white hover:text-[#2b9ceb] hover:bg-opacity-50 
  rounded-full cursor-pointer" @click="loopCurrentTrack">
            <Repeat class="block" :fillColor="isRepeatOn ? '#2b9ceb' : undefined" :size="17"/>
            </div>
```

The function works in terms of turning the loop on and off and will repeat the track when true and let the track play the next track when false. However, if I click play on another song in the array, the isRepeatOn remains set to true and then the currentTrack, because it is different doesn't repeat, but also, doesn't continue to the next track when it finishes. How can I fix this? I think I need to set either the watcher or the function to change the isRepeatOn to false when the track doesn't match the currentTrack? But I'm not sure on if this is right or even how to do this.

Update:

Here is the full script setup without the imports. The code is for a music player that recieves the audio from the array when the songRow component containing the play function is triggered.

```
        const useSong = useSongStore()
        const { isPlaying, audio, currentTrack, trackTime, isTrackTimeTotal, currentVolume} = storeToRefs(useSong)

        let isHover = ref(false)
        let isVolumeHover = ref(false)
        let isVersionsHover = ref(false)
        let isTrackTimeCurrent = ref('0:00')
        let seeker = ref(null)
        let seekerContainer = ref(null)
        let range = ref(0)
        let isRepeatOn = ref(false)

        onMounted(() => {

            if (audio.value) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    const duration = audio.value.duration;
                    const minutes = Math.floor(duration / 60);
                    const seconds = Math.floor(duration % 60);
                    isTrackTimeTotal.value = minutes+':'+seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')
                    timeupdate()
                    loadmetadata()
                }, 300)
            }
            if (currentTrack.value) { 
                seeker.value.addEventListener("change", function () {
                    const time = audio.value.duration * (seeker.value.value / 100);
                    audio.value.currentTime = time;
                });
            
                seeker.value.addEventListener("mousedown", function () {
                    audio.value.pause();
                    isPlaying.value = false
                });
                seeker.value.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
                    audio.value.play();
                    isPlaying.value = true
                });
                seekerContainer.value.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                    const clickPosition = (e.pageX - seekerContainer.value.offsetLeft) / seekerContainer.value.offsetWidth;
                    const time = audio.value.duration * clickPosition;
                    audio.value.currentTime = time;
                    seeker.value.value = (100 / audio.value.duration) * audio.value.currentTime;
                });
            }
        })


        const timeupdate = () => {
            audio.value.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
                var minutes = Math.floor(audio.value.currentTime / 60);
                var seconds = Math.floor(audio.value.currentTime - minutes * 60);
                isTrackTimeCurrent.value = minutes+':'+seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')
                trackTime.value = isTrackTimeCurrent.value
                const value = (100 / audio.value.duration) * audio.value.currentTime;
                range.value = value
                seeker.value.value = value;
            });
        }
        const loadmetadata = () => {
            audio.value.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
                const duration = audio.value.duration;
                const minutes = Math.floor(duration / 60);
                const seconds = Math.floor(duration % 60);
                isTrackTimeTotal.value = minutes+':'+seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0')
            });
        }

        const loopCurrentTrack = () => {
        isRepeatOn.value = !isRepeatOn.value;
        if (isRepeatOn.value) {
            audio.value.addEventListener("ended", function () {
            audio.value.currentTime = 0;
            audio.value.play();
            });
        } else {
            audio.value.removeEventListener("ended", null);
        }
        }



        watch(() => audio.value, () => {
            timeupdate()
            loadmetadata()
        })

        watch(
        () => isTrackTimeCurrent.value,
        (time) => {
            if (time === isTrackTimeTotal.value && !isRepeatOn.value) {
            useSong.nextSong(currentTrack.value);
            }
        }
        );
```

The Pinia store contains the actions for playing the current track, skipping back a song, skipping to next song etc. I can add that if needed.

Comment: This should be simple; it would be nice to see more complete code. When you start playing a new song, it should override everything else that's going on. In any case I would think your func `loopCurrentTrack` would be named something like `trackFinished` and inside contains all logic pertaining to what the next event is (play loop, play next, play nothing, etc). It's strange seeing the watcher for `isTrackTimeCurrent`; when does this get triggered? It would be nice to see how these things get called.

Comment: @Kalnode I have added the script setup. I have tried the following with the watcher but it didn't work:

`watch(
  [currentTrack, isTrackTimeCurrent],
  ([track, time]) => {
    if (time === isTrackTimeTotal.value && !isRepeatOn.value) {
      useSong.nextSong(track);
    } else if (track !== currentTrack.value) {
      isRepeatOn.value = false;
    }
  }
);
`

Comment: All else aside, I find it peculiar that you're only setting `audio.value.addEventListener("ended", function () {...` inside the loop check function, and further as an inline function. Shouldn't you be enabling this listener absolutely any time audio starts? You have audio triggers elsewhere, but don't set an "ended" listener in those places. Then, also the callback should be to a proper function... I'll use a super-literal name here: `function decideWhatToDoWhenTrackFinishes()`. I have a feeling your watchers are overkill and you're unnecessarily using resources. Watchers tend to be "heavy".

Comment: @Kalnode I'm using the event listener to wait until the end of the song (after pressing the loop button) before playing the song again. So I click the Repeat icon, that triggers the loopCurrentTrack function which sets the isRepeatOn to true. Then if isRepeatOn is true the event listener waits until the currentTrack has ended and then plays the currentTrack. The watcher is used to wait until the currentTrack has ended and if isRepeatOn is false to automatically load the nextSong via its function. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The function works but I think the watcher needs to be changed so that if a user clicks play on a different track while isRepeatOn is set to true, then it turns isRepeatOn to false so the watcher will continue to play through the tracks as normal until the user presses the Repeat button again.